# C++ two dimensional array containing string and int

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, int

I have to make a table with a two dimensional array in c++. The array will need to hold two strings and two integers. 
Is it possible to have strings and integers in the same array? And how?

Please help ! I`m new to programming

Comment: Smells a lot like XY problem. What is the underlying problem you want to solve? Why can't you for instance use two distinct arrays?

Comment: Well, I have to make a 4x4 table. The first two columns will contain names and the last two will contain age numbers.

Comment: Consider using a struct instead of a vector to represent your columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you probably want an array (or vector) of structures, where each structure contains a string and an int:

```
struct person {
    int age;
    std::string name;
};

std::vector<person> people(2);
```

In this case, you refer to the "rows" by number, and the "columns" by name, so the first string would be: `people[0].name` and the second integer would be `people[1].age`.